# How do I type validate values in a map?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, Object>` which I call **myMap**, and I want to iterate through each key and ensure that its value is either of type `String`, `int` & `Boolean`.

I've tried something along these lines:

```
myMap.entrySet().forEach(key -> myMap.get(key));
```

I don't know how to do the actual check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check all of `myMap.values()` with `Stream#allMatch`.

```java
boolean pass = myMap.values().stream().allMatch(o -> o instanceof String || 
                    o instanceof Integer || o instanceof Boolean);
```

Note that it is impossible for the value to be of type `int`; it can only be the wrapper class `Integer`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution:

```
Set<Class> expectedTypes = Set.of(String.class, Integer.class, Boolean.class);
boolean check = myList.values().stream()
        .allMatch(v -> expectedTypes.contains(v.getClass()));
```

Or:

```
boolean check = myList.values().stream()
        .map(Object::getClass)
        .allMatch(expectedTypes::contains);
```

The idea here is to create a set of accepted types, then you can use `contains(v.getClass())` to check if the type is correct or not.

[**Full example here.**](http://tpcg.io/_LHYDE3)

Comment: Nice answer. I would use `Set` here, though.

Comment: @Unmitigated exactly, I edit it my answer, thank you :)

Comment: Note this works because `String`, `Integer`, and `Boolean` are all `final`. But if someone is using non-final classes, and they want to check the values are an _instance of_ some type, rather than _exactly_ that type, this won't work. Also, it should probably be `Set<Class<?>>`, as `Class` is a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

depends on what you need, but following code will filter out all entries where value is not of given type(s)

```java
private Map<String, Object> getSupportedTypes(final Map<String, Object> source) {
    return source.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof Integer
                    || entry.getValue() instanceof String
                    || entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```